# hiding specific text (php) using echo str?

Tags: php, xpath, echo, str-replace

Having an issue making this work with my PHP code. (i'm really bad at php fyi)

```
echo str_replace("DJIA", "", "REGISTER DJIA here");
```

The above should exclude any text that says DJIA, it should hide it.

However when used in the below code, which scrapes DJIA stock information and redisplays it, it's not getting rid of the "DJIA." Any thoughts?

```
<?php 

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
echo str_replace("DJIA", "", "REGISTER DJIA here");
}
```

Comment: the code is working fine

Comment: It's not for me, it doesn't replace the text DJIA. this is the result I'm getting...if that were working as I'm intending, "DJIA" would never appear. DJIA 21271.97 +89.44(0.42%)REGISTER hereNASDAQ 6207.92 -113.85(-1.80%)REGISTER hereS&P 500 2431.77 -2.02(-0.08%)REGISTER

Comment: its not the same DJIA ,if it were it should have appeared in between REGISTER here

Comment: Nihal, thanks for the response. Still having issues. All I'm trying to do is get rid of any part that says "DJIA". Would this do it, putting something like this as the last line of the php code? Can't seem to get it working. echo str_replace("DJIA", "", "");   Appreciate your help

Comment: ok so is DJIA part of textContent ?

Comment: yes "DJIA" is part of the result my website loads. it's being scraped/xpath from another source via php. I feel like I've stumbled upon a few different ways to hide specific words, but I'm more having trouble fitting it in correctly with the above php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
echo str_replace("DJIA", "", $entry->textContent." REGISTER DJIA here");
```

in place of :

```
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
echo str_replace("DJIA", "", "REGISTER DJIA here");
```

Comment: thanks for the your answer. not able to get that to work, is it because perhaps where I'm placing it in the code? Here's the full code: <?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
echo str_replace("DJIA", "", $entry->textContent." REGISTER here");
}

Comment: basically i put your new code right after     echo trim($entry->textContent);

Comment: The register text appears but at the end of the text, merely because it's at the end of the php. It doesn't replace anything for me

Comment: Thank you very much Nihal. I actually never wanted the REGISTER DIJA here type of command in the php. But to get rid of it was simple, I just did one single space....aka empty space, in that part of the code. And naturally, the output is negligible. So alas, it works perfect now. Thanks very much for all your help!